# not possible run windows from other disk after install ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have this disks

```
sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for grek: 
Disk /dev/loop0: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 63.28 MiB, 66355200 bytes, 129600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 346.33 MiB, 363151360 bytes, 709280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 240.61 MiB, 252301312 bytes, 492776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 49.84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 73.85 MiB, 77438976 bytes, 151248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 466.54 MiB, 489201664 bytes, 955472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC  WDS500G2B0A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AE7B31F8-73AF-4BF3-AA33-EA439B3F3678

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 975728749 975489134 465.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  975730688 976771071   1040384   508M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-08W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd7c84f4f

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          1026048 1561205735 1560179688   744G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       1951834112 1953519615    1685504   823M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb4       1561206782 1951832063  390625282 186.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1561206784 1951832063  390625280 186.3G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdc: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: PNY CS900 240GB 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdae90987

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *         2048   1187839   1185792   579M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2         1187840 467779754 466591915 222.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3       467781632 468856831   1075200   525M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


Disk /dev/loop8: 174.21 MiB, 182677504 bytes, 356792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

eailer i have windows boot manager it has 2 windows , one broken, second working.

I install ubuntu - have hope that he install grup and it grub i can select linux / windows on disk x , windows on disk y

but i get : linux windows boot loader

when i select win boot loader he try repair (with fail) and way that work before install ubuntu. -> run windows from other disk , after click it run. but now is back to grub,

how i can fix this ?

i try boot-repair , grub customizer - but there is no option run windows on disk x, only win boot loader that dont work,,,

Comment: You always need to be careful to install in same boot mode, or all installs in UEFI mode or all inBIOS mode. Windows requires gpt partitioning with UEFI and MBR(msdos) with BIOS. Ubuntu will let you use UEFI in MBR but really should not. You have one UEFI/gpt drive and two MBR drives. Grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode, so Ubuntu needs to be UEFI.  converting sdb & sdc to gpt from MBR will erase drives so have good backups.